# Images are damaged with Spring and Feign Client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm sorry for my bad English :(

I want to upload image file with Feign Client, but images are damaged on the server app.

```js
// CLIENT APP
@FeignClient(name = "media-client", url = "${api.base-path}/media")
public interface MediaClient {
    @PostMapping
    String uploadMedia(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file);
}

// SERVER APP
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
String uploadMedia(@RequestPart MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), Paths.get("/home/m/Desktop").resolve(UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg"));
    return null;
}
```

Same image saved with client app and server app. But the result is as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbiPS.png

What's wrong? Please help me.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have tested that file locally, it's not damaged before the upload?

Comment: @sniperd yes, I have tested file locally. it's damaged after the upload.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Feign encoder for multipart/form-data forms.
Steps:

First, Include this dependency to your project's pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign.form</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-form</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, add this configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Encoder encoder() {
        return new SpringFormEncoder();
    }
 }
```

and change your annotation:

```
@FeignClient(name = "media-client", url = "${api.base-path}/media", configuration = FeignClientConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: Hi @Shchipunov. Thanks for your answer. I have already added these dependencies. Files are uploaded but damaged on the server app.